# Rails - Devise Async (sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I'm using devise-asyn gem with sidekiq backend, but when send some email, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)):

devise-async (0.7.0) lib/devise/async/model.rb:27:in `send_devise_notification'
```

any ideas how to fix it? thanks!

EDIT:

Some of my setup:
I'm using Rails 5

Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise' ,'~> 4.1.0' 
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra', require: false
gem 'devise-async'
```

devise_async.rb intializer:

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.backend = :sidekiq
  config.queue   = :mailer
end
```

User class (renamed it, it's called Usuario):

```
class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :async, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 ...
end
```

sidekiq.yml config:

```
:queues:
  - default
  - [mailers, 2]
```

I'm running sidekiq with:

```
bundle exec sidekiq --environment development -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Already restarted rails server, sidekiq and redis server, but still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **gem 'devise' ,'~> 4.1.0'**

/config/initializers/devise_async.rb

```
Devise::Async.setup do |config|
  config.backend = :sidekiq
  config.queue   = :mailer
end
```

/app/models/user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,   :async, :confirmable 
   end
```

config/sidekiq.yml

```
:queues:
  - default
  - [mailers, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, but I still get the same error... added some info to the question, take a look pls!